# jQuery.Ajax Post to webservice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to post data to my backend system (SAP). I'm trying to use the following code:

Hardcoded the URL example:

```
  var dataString = ""
    //Add TO SAP.
     var aData =  
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                //contentType: "application/xml",
                url: "http://delyo001.you.local:8000/sap/bc/youconsulting/ws/rest/anonymous/z_names_post?firstname=testz&lastname=zefzef",  // for different servers cross-domain restrictions need to be handled
                data: dataString,
                //dataType: "json"

                success: function(xml) { // callback called when data is received
                    //oModel.setData(data);             // fill the received data into the JSONModel
                    alert("success to post");
                },

                error: function(xml) { // callback called when data is received
                    //oModel.setData(data);             // fill the received data into the JSONModel
                    alert("fail to  post");
                    alert(xml);
                }
            });
```

The webservice works via SOAPUI. But not via this way.

Can anyone please guide to what's wrong with this code.

Kind regards,
Vincent

Comment: Yes the alert fail to post is triggered, the problem is it works fine in soapui. I can't get any specific error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try set a header as:

> header : {   "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it did not work, firebug reveals more information:

http://i.imgur.com/DvCOF.png

Comment: New error with this code:
http://pastie.org/5457519

NetworkError: 405 Method not allowed - http://delyo001.you.local:8000/sap/bc/youconsulting/ws/rest/anonymous/z_names_post